# what am I doing wrong in the following

Tags: calculus

Question:
Calculate the equation of tangent at the point $(4,2)$ if $y=\sqrt{X}$

My answer:

$(x_0,y_0) = (4,2)$,

$f'(X) = y^{1/2} y'= 1/2X^{-1/2}$

$f'(4) = (\frac{1}{2})(4)^{-1/2} = 1$

$y-y_0=f'(X)(x-X_0)$

$y-2=1 (X-4)$

$y= x-2$

Correct answer:

$y=\frac{1}{4}x +1$

what am I doing wrong? thanks

Comment: You calculated $4^{1/2}$ instead of $4^{-1/2}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x} \sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}$

When $x = 4$, $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}=\frac{1}{4}$.

So the equation of the line is

$y-2=\frac{1}{4}(x-4)$

$y=\frac{1}{4}x +1$

Answer (score 0):

You miscalculated the value of $f'(4) = \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{4}} = \frac{1}{4}$. Reapply this value to your problem and it will yield the right answer.